# How to prevent DateComponents from updating for time zone

Tags: swift, date, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get date components from a date value from an API endpoint. I need to preserve the date values as they are already adjusted for time zone. Unfortunately, I have no control over how the API returns a date value.

When I get the date value (`sessionTime`) from the API, it is returned as follows:

```
2017-12-05 08:00:00 +0000
```

I need to set up a local notification based on that time, however, when I try to extract components from that date object with the following code:

```
let notifyTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
     [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: sessionTime)
```

I get this:

```
year: 2017 month: 12 day: 5 hour: 2 minute: 0 second: 0 isLeapMonth: false
```

I am six hours from GMT so it is obvious what is going on, but I wish I could prevent it and extract the date components exactly as they are. The desired output would be:

```
year: 2017 month: 12 day: 5 hour: 8 minute: 0 second: 0 isLeapMonth: false
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the timeZone that DateComponents uses.

Like this:

```
let notifyTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: sessionTime)
```